# AS3: How to make a stamp-like effect [specifically with the coding I am using]?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flashdevelop

I am VERY new to Flash and Actionscript. I am having a pretty bad time grasping some elements.

I am currently making a program based on a beginner's tutorial I found online and I have edited it to how I have wanted so far with the exception of making a stamp-like effect.

What happen's so far is simple: it generates a smiley face vector image, if the user clicks on it, it follows the cursor until the user clicks again where it will stay and no longer follow the cursor.

What I am trying to do is modify the click event to somehow not only place down the vector but essentially make a new one that will follow the cursor and allow another one to be places, so on and so forth.

The code I have so far is below:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Lyon's Den Gaming
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public var happyface:Sprite;
        public var stampcount:Number = 0;
        public var happyfacecursor:Boolean;

        public var mouseListener:Object = new Object();

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point

            happyface = new Sprite();
            addChild(happyface);

            //This will draw the main circle O
            happyface.graphics.beginFill(0xf2f75b);
            happyface.graphics.lineStyle(6, 0x000000);
            happyface.graphics.drawCircle(800 / 2, 600 / 2, 200);
            happyface.graphics.endFill();

            //This will draw the eyes ^^
            happyface.graphics.lineStyle(8);
            happyface.graphics.moveTo(325, 170);
            happyface.graphics.lineTo(325, 245);

            happyface.graphics.lineStyle(8);
            happyface.graphics.moveTo(466, 170);
            happyface.graphics.lineTo(466, 245);

            //This will draw the mouth :D
            happyface.graphics.lineStyle(8);
            happyface.graphics.moveTo(275, 340);
            happyface.graphics.lineTo(525, 340);

            happyface.graphics.lineStyle(8);
            happyface.graphics.beginFill(0xdb3d3d);
            happyface.graphics.moveTo(275, 340);
            happyface.graphics.cubicCurveTo(280, 500, 520, 500, 525, 340);
            happyface.graphics.endFill();

            //this scales it down and places it where I want

            happyface.scaleX = .15;
            happyface.scaleY = .15;
            happyface.x = 335;
            happyface.y = 265;


            //This will add mouse input!
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, MouseMoveHappyFace);
            happyface.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, SelectHappyFace);




        }   
        public function MouseMoveHappyFace(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
        if (happyfacecursor)
        {

            happyface.x = mouseX - happyface.width;
            happyface.y = mouseY - happyface.height / (1.4);
        } else {
            happyfacecursor = false;
            addChild(happyface);
        }

        }

        public function SelectHappyFace(e:MouseEvent):void
        {

            if (happyfacecursor)
            happyfacecursor = false;
            else
            happyfacecursor = true;

        }






    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use the drag and drop methods? When you click the `happyface` end or start the drag:

**Edited:** you won't need your `MouseMoveHappyFace` function with this:

**Edited 2:** here you have a new method that creates a happy face at a  time. I haven't tried this but it should work.

```
   public var happyface:Sprite;
   public var stampcount:int = 0;
   public var happyfacecursor:Boolean;

   public function Main():void {
      if (stage) init();
      else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
   }

   private function init(e:Event = null):void {
      removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
      // entry point

      // Create the first stamp
      addNewHappyFace();
   }

   public function addNewHappyFace():void {

      // This method creates a new happyFace, adds it and asigns it to 
      // the global happyface variable

      var aux = new Sprite();
      this.addChild(aux);

      stampcount++;

      //This will draw the main circle O
      aux.graphics.beginFill(0xf2f75b);
      aux.graphics.lineStyle(6, 0x000000);
      aux.graphics.drawCircle(800 / 2, 600 / 2, 200);
      aux.graphics.endFill();

      //This will draw the eyes ^^
      aux.graphics.lineStyle(8);
      aux.graphics.moveTo(325, 170);
      aux.graphics.lineTo(325, 245);
      aux.graphics.lineStyle(8);
      aux.graphics.moveTo(466, 170);
      aux.graphics.lineTo(466, 245);

      //This will draw the mouth :D
      aux.graphics.lineStyle(8);
      aux.graphics.moveTo(275, 340);
      aux.graphics.lineTo(525, 340);
      aux.graphics.lineStyle(8);
      aux.graphics.beginFill(0xdb3d3d);
      aux.graphics.moveTo(275, 340);
      aux.graphics.cubicCurveTo(280, 500, 520, 500, 525, 340);
      aux.graphics.endFill();

      //this scales it down and places it where I want
      aux.scaleX = .15;
      aux.scaleY = .15;
      aux.x = 335;
      aux.y = 265;

      //This will add mouse input!
      aux.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, SelectHappyFace);

      happyface = aux;
   }

   public function SelectHappyFace(e:MouseEvent):void{
      if (happyfacecursor) }
         happyface.startDrag(); // To make the object follow the mouse
         happyfacecursor = false;
      } else {
         happyface.stopDrag(); // To drop the object where you want

         // This will prevent that when clicking on an already placed stam i would
         // make the last one created to move
         happyface.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, SelectHappyFace);         

         happyfacecursor = true;

         // Now create and add a new HappyFace clip here
         addNewHappyFace()
      }
   }
```

Comment: Does this still cover my part of the question about leaving a clone of itself behind? The ultimate goal is essentially a multiple stamp effect where if the user drags, clicks, or whatever it will create a new happyface and allow placement, so on and so forth.

Comment: I am a real noob when it comes to flash and actionscript. how exactly would I add the "new HappyFace clip"? I am unfamiliar with how that would be done.

Comment: I Updated my exaple including a class that creates a new happy face everytime you call it, it uses the code in you `init()` function. I hope it works fine :)